# C++ COM ATL VariantChangeType causes WSH to crash

Tags: c++, variant, wsh

I have following line of code in my COM ATL project which causes WSH to crash:

```
Result = VariantChangeType(&Variant, &Variant, VARIANT_NOUSEROVERRIDE, VT_UINT);
```

When above function gets called prior to crash, `Variant`'s type is `VT_BSTR`, that's why I used `VARIANT_NOUSEROVERRIDE` flag. I tried removing flag with no success.

What is wrong here for WSH to crash? I am sure that this is the line that causes the crash because message box which is prior to this line is displaying but message box after this line isn't displaying. Then Windows says:

> Microsoft ® Windows Based Script Host has stopped working

Is my syntax wrong here?

Comment: Whether this is the cause or not, you don't generally want to use types like `VT_UINT` with old COM hosts. `VT_I4` should be the right one.

Comment: @RomanR. You may be right, but when I attached wscript.exe process to Visual Studio Debugger and checked status, it said `wscript.exe has triggered a breakpoint. occurred` just before crashed dialog appears. :-(

Comment: @RomanR. tried with `VT_I4`, same thing happened. Can I share this full code with you?

Comment: It is a good idea to post both ATL C++ and script code snippets because your question in its present form is not well defined.

Comment: @RomanR. I used `CComVariant` class and it worked fine, unlike before I am getting a `Type Mismatch` when function passes a `BSTR` like `123456Hello` and try to convert to `unsigned int`, and no more breakpoints. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this issue by using `CComVariant::ChangeType` instead of using `VariantChangeType` function like below:

```
CComVariant CV = Variant;

HRESULT Result = CV.ChangeType(VT_I2);
```